# How can I save many sentences efficiently in Android?

Tags: android, database, android-sqlite

I am developing an app for Android which will have many sentences organized with categories. Besides, this app must upgrade the sentences with a mysql database.

My question is: How can I save many sentences efficiently?

I have thought creating a sqlite database in my pc and add it to the app project. Is that possible?
Maybe, could I do another thing?

Comment: Why not use the android sqllite? How many sentences you need? why not setting the sentences as a static in "setting" class

Comment: you can use SQLite DB on android to save your data and later on use Sync Adapter to synchronize your local SQLite DB with MySQL DB on your server

Comment: Thanks for your answer. @user1799320 Could I create the sqlite in my pc to add 50000 sentences more less and later copy the database to my project? Must I create a SQLite 3 or 2?

Comment: Current SQLite version is 3.

Comment: You might want to make a csv file containing all the 50K+ sentences and then import all of them into SQLite

Comment: Thanks @Bob Malooga I will do it.

Comment: I think it's the easyest way to first collect all your sentences and then make a batch insert all at once.

Comment: Assuming this is something that only you the developer needs to do, and not any of your users...if your device is rooted, you can drop a SQLite database file directly into your app.

Comment: Thanks @Greg So... I would only need droping the database in my app and I could work with SQLiteOpenHelper and the file. Is that true?

Comment: It's been a while since I did this, but basically yes.  I don't think you'll be able to use SQLiteOpenHelper to edit the database while it's in the app, but you can export/import the database file back and forth between then as needed, pretty quickly.

Comment: I think I will do the same that did this page: http://es.wikicode.org/index.php?title=Usar_nuestra_propia_sqlite_en_Android&redirect=no/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like you said; create your database using sqlite on desktop and then include it in your application in the `\assets` folder. Use it normally in your application.

Remember to always us `_id` as the primary key in your tables.

For more details check this [blog post](http://blog.kdehairy.com/using-a-preloaded-sqlite-database-with-sqliteopenhelper/)